# pyspark join multiple conditions

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How I can specify lot of conditions in
pyspark when I use `.join()`

Example :
with hive :

```
query= "select a.NUMCNT,b.NUMCNT as RNUMCNT ,a.POLE,b.POLE as RPOLE,a.ACTIVITE,b.ACTIVITE as RACTIVITE FROM rapexp201412 b \
    join rapexp201412 a where (a.NUMCNT=b.NUMCNT and a.ACTIVITE = b.ACTIVITE and a.POLE =b.POLE  )\
```

But in PySpark I don't know how to make it because the following:

```
df_rapexp201412.join(df_aeveh,df_rapexp2014.ACTIVITE==df_rapexp2014.ACTIVITE and df_rapexp2014.POLE==df_aeveh.POLE,'inner')
```

It does not work!!

Comment: could you plz paste the error message for DataFrame.join? or try to use the keyBy/join in RDD, it support the equi-join condition very well.

Comment: Use & in between and make sure to put each condition in ()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to join on multiple columns in Pyspark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33745964/how-to-join-on-multiple-columns-in-pyspark)

Answer (score 57):

Quoting from spark docs:

(https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=dataframe%20join#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.join)

> join(other, on=None, how=None) Joins with another DataFrame, using the
>   given join expression.
>
> The following performs a full outer join between df1 and df2.
>
> Parameters:    other – Right side of the join on – a string for join
>   column name, a list of column names, , a join expression (Column) or a
>   list of Columns. If on is a string or a list of string indicating the
>   name of the join column(s), the column(s) must exist on both sides,
>   and this performs an inner equi-join. how – str, default ‘inner’. One
>   of inner, outer, left_outer, right_outer, semijoin.

```
>>> df.join(df2, df.name == df2.name, 'outer').select(df.name, df2.height).collect()
 [Row(name=None, height=80), Row(name=u'Alice', height=None), Row(name=u'Bob', height=85)]


>>> cond = [df.name == df3.name, df.age == df3.age]
>>> df.join(df3, cond, 'outer').select(df.name, df3.age).collect()
[Row(name=u'Bob', age=5), Row(name=u'Alice', age=2)]
```

So you need to use the "condition as a list" option like in the last example.

Comment: this cond = [df.name == df3.name, df.age == df3.age] means an "and" or an "or"? what if i want df.name == df1.name OR df.age == df1.age. how would that work?

Comment: Use `cond = [(df.name == df3.name) | (df.age == df3.age)]` instead, where `|` represents the "or" condition.

Comment: Using a list of join expressions using strings instead of hard coded column names is also possible e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45813075/38368

Comment: Would be helpful if the docs mentioned that if `on` is a list, it is reduced via boolean `AND`.

Answer (score 10):

```
>>> cond = [df.name == df3.name, df.age == df3.age]
>>> df.join(df3, cond, 'outer').select(df.name, df3.age).collect()
[Row(name=u'Bob', age=5), Row(name=u'Alice', age=2)]
```

This did not work with pyspark 1.3.1. I was getting "AssertionError: joinExprs should be Column"

Instead, I used raw sql to join the data frames as shown below

```
df.registerTempTable("df")
df3.registerTempTable("df3")

sqlContext.sql("Select df.name,df3.age from df outer join df3 on df.name = df3.name and df.age =df3.age").collect()
```

Answer (score 9):

Reporting @S V Praveen reply as I had problem to express `OR` in the join condition:

```
cond = [df.surname == df3.surname, 
        (df.name == df3.name) | (df.age == df3.age),
        df.orders >= df3.orders ]

df.join(df3, cond, 'outer')
```

Where `|` represents the "OR" condition

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the following

```
cond = [((df1.col1 == df2.col2) &\
         (df1.col3 == df2.col4))]

joined_df = df1.join(df2, on = cond, how = "inner")
```