# Spark Multiple Conditions Join

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I am using spark sql to join three tables, however i get error with multiple column conditions.

```
test_table = (T1.join(T2,T1.dtm == T2.kids_dtm, "inner")
          .join(T3, T3.kids_dtm == T1.dtm
                and T2.room_id == T3.room_id
                and T2.book_id == T3.book_id, "inner"))
```

ERROR:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.7.0-1.cdh5.7.0.p0.45/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/column.py", line 447, in __nonzero__
    raise ValueError("Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', "
ValueError: Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions.
```

Instead of specifying "and", i have tried putting "&" and "&&" , but none of these work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Nvm, following works with use of "&" and brackets:

```
test_table = (T1.join(T2,T1.dtm == T2.kids_dtm, "inner")
      .join(T3, (T3.kids_dtm == T1.dtm)
            & (T2.room_id == T3.room_id)
            & (T2.book_id == T3.book_id), "inner"))
```

Comment: Or you can put your conditions to be 'and'ed in a list; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/34463562/1843329 for an example.

Comment: what about an OR instead? X or Y, how would it work in a list?

Comment: Or you can use a list of conditions with variable names like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/45813075/38368, which is useful if the column names are calculated e.g. by an index in a loop.