# Pyspark Dataframe Lambda Map Function of SQL Query

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose we have a `pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame` object:

```
df = sc.parallelize([['John', 'male', 26], 
                 ['Teresa', 'female', 25], 
                 ['Jacob', 'male', 6]]).toDF(['name', 'gender', 'age'])
```

I have a function that runs `sql` query for each rows of the DataFrame:

```
def getInfo(data):
    param_name = data['name']
    param_gender = data['gender']
    param_age = data['age']
    
    sql_query = "SELECT * FROM people_info WHERE name = '{0}' AND gender = '{1}' AND age = {2}".format(param_name, param_gender, param_age)
    info = info.append(spark.sql(sql_query))
    
    return info
```

I am trying to run function each rows by `map`:

```
df_info = df.rdd.map(lambda x: getInfo(x))
```

I got errors

```
PicklingError: Could not serialize object: Exception: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is actually telling you what exactly what is wrong.  Your function is trying to access SparkContext(`sparck.sql(sql_query)`) from inside a transformation( `df.rdd.map(lambda x: getInfo(x))`).

Here's what I think you are trying to do:

```
df = sc.parallelize([['John', 'male', 26], 
                 ['Teresa', 'female', 25], 
                 ['Jacob', 'male', 6]]).toDF(['name', 'gender', 'age'])
people = spark.table("people_info")

people.join(df, on=[people.name == df.name, people.gender == df.gender, people.age == df.age], how="inner")
```

Here's a couple [other ways to do a join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33745964/how-to-join-on-multiple-columns-in-pyspark).